# How can I save my CNN tensorflow model in .txt format in single file?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am training a CNN using tensorflow. I want to convert the .data, .meta, .index files in the checkpoint directory to a single .txt files. Can that be done ?

Comment: Why would you like to do that?

Comment: I am using it in my application along with json. If not txt file, I want to save the model as biases {} gradients {}  variables{} etc to a single file. Is that possible ?